# How to reuse activity components in a viewHolder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Initially I had an activity which shows some data after an api call. Now I need to convert this activity to a recyclerView.

The activity also had some async calls, means after the very first call it takes the data and call the second api and then update the ui.

My project is in mvp architecture. I wanted to know what component can I reuse in my view holder so I can achieve a list similar to my activiy with minimum code. Because copy pasting all the click interactions and api call is of too much pain.

I can provide code samples if needed. Currently I took a list of elements in the beginning for my recyclerview and started redoing the whole work.

Comment: provide sample please

Answer (score 0):

Make your methods public which you want to reuse and call them like this

```
((Activity)holder.itemView.getContext()).method();
```

Comment: I would use a interface for this kind of iterations. But my question was do I need to code most of the things again? Click interactions , api call etc?  And my project is too complex I described here in a simple way.

Comment: Ok. Load a fragment it activity and pass data to this fragment.So you can show your recycler view on Fragment and and can reuse the code